# Onenote 2013 embedded Excel list blurry in web view

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote-2013

I embedded an Excel table into a OneNote page (to track a Todo list). It displays fine in the OneNote 2013 desktop app, and I can edit it there directly and also open it for editing in Excel.

When I use the web view tough in Internet Explorer, it displays the Excel table all blurry and it cannot be edited (looks like an image).

Can I fix that or is that a limitation of Office Online? (I assume that is the technology behind the web view, I cannot get version information, it is company hosted. Some colleagues use web view rather than desktop app.)

Comment: Is this office 365?

Comment: I don't see the version. Help points to office.com, though the URL is a company one. I suppose it is 365 though.